# How to query this column so that only entries from within the last week are taken

Tags: php, mysql

I have column called 'last updated' of this format: 2009-10-13 09:20:30 and I want to select all entries in the column that have a date that is within the last 7 days of the time the query is ran. I am using php in the backend for this query along with mysql.

I am constructing a large query, this will be part of it.

Thanks very much if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short example on how to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable AS t1
WHERE t1.last_updated > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

The documentation can be found [here in the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub).

Comment: Phpmyadmin tells me there is an error in the syntax near ) if I use this

Comment: check the table name and field names if they match. i tried it myself, it didn't cause any syntax error.

Comment: Yeah I've triple checked the table and field names and it doesn't work. I'm not even adding anything to your query, just running it in the sql tab of phpmyadmin

Comment: Ok, it's working now if I put the table in ` ` marks. Thanks.

Comment: Try `SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`;  ... does this work? If yes, triple check the table name and the field name involved here.

Answer (score 0):

From [MySQL Docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub): `SELECT something FROM tbl_name WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= date_col`

Comment: As I said: It comes directly from the MySQL docu and I think everyone should be able, to handle it, to change the `30` to a `7` :)

Comment: Phpmyadmin tells me there is an error in the syntax near ) if I use this

Comment: Could you post your complete query?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you want and whether you care about the time part. If the current time is, say, 5pm, and you want all entries from the day 7 days ago (and not just the entries from 5pm on the day 7 days ago) you will need to make the query a bit more complex.

```
SELECT *
FROM `yourtable` AS t1
WHERE DATE( t1.last_updated ) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

In your example, this query will give you all entries since 2009-10-06 00:00:00 rather than entries since 2009-10-06 09:20:30 which is what you will get if you compare your column directly with DATE() less 7 days.